# Adding Accessory to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've got a UITableView displayed on screen for a while. In each cell is a song and artist name. In the background, each song and artist name is searched for online (using the Spotify API). It finds the URL to play one song, and then moves on to the next one! :) Sounds simple... but what I want is when each song is found, for the Checkmark accessory to appear in that row.

Currently i've got the following code to do this...

```
[[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentConnectionNumber inSection:0]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
[table setNeedsDisplay];
```

But all that happens is when all of the songs has been found, THEN the checkmarks appear... Why is this and how can I make the checkmarks appear one at a time?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the checkmark in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellForIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellTitle = [self cellTitleForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // You need to implement this method
    BOOL hasURL = [self hasURLForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // You need to implement this method

    cell.textLabel.text = cellTitle;

    if (hasURL)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Then reload the cells when your request finishes

```
- (void)myRequestFinished:(SomeKindOfWebRequest *)webRequest {

    NSIndexPath *indexPathToReload = [self indexPathForWebRequest:webRequest]; // You need to implement this method
    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathToReload];

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimtation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't working unfortunately. The code is running through it at the right time, and setting the cell.accessoryStyle. But it's not updating on the view.

Comment: My mistake, it should be `accessoryType`, not `accessoryStyle`. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Indeed, I corrected that, but the changes still do not occur until the last request has finished despite actually executing that code at the right point in the workflow...

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData` on your `UITableView` when each request finishes?

Comment: Yep,    reloadData waits until the last request is finished.    reloadRowsAtIndexPath: works after each request but doesn't seem to affect what is actually displayed.

Comment: I've amended my answer to show the best way to reload the rows. Are you sure you're doing this?

Comment: `[table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentConnectionNumber inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` Where `currentConnectionNumber` is the row of the UITableView.

Comment: My only advice left then is to put a breakpoint on `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` and one on `[table reload...]` and see if it happens as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than doing this you can set a bool flag for as per your requirement and add your checkmark logic in

> cellForRowAtIndexPath:

and if that flag is true add accessary checkmark otherwise don't.

```
  if (isValid) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }
    else{

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't working unfortunately. The code is running through it at the right time, and setting the cell.accessoryStyle. But it's not updating on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reloading your tableView using

> [yourtableView reloadData]

when your data modifies.